# Display images in textview and make downloadable

Tags: android, retrofit

I get a html content from json with retrofit2.
json:

```
"content": " hello word! <img src="test.jpg">"
```

I want when the content is shown,images in content display like this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMcrp.jpg)

there is button on center of image that after click on it , image downloaded and show like this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBVA5.jpg)

what is the code for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is a snap of code that saves an image in internal storage of the device:

```
 public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
        try {
   // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
   // the OutputStream
   FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
   image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
   fos.close();

   return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
     return false;
   }
}
```

Call this method in button's onClick i suppose.